# Avoid comment-line to move cursor to beginning of heading (ORGMODE)

Tags: emacs, cursor-position

Everytime I use "comment-line" in a elisp bunch of code, the cursor moves up. This is annoying.
Is there a way to comment line by line in Elisp so that the cursor stays in the very same line?

This happens in OrgMode blocks, but not in Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this behavior is hard-baked into the code of `comment-line`. However, it's easy enough to create a variation of that function that leaves point in place, either by [adivising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `comment-line` or by writing a separate function like so:

```
(defun comment-line-leave-point (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (comment-line n)))
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the behaviour of your function is the same as the comment-line.

Comment: Not for me. If I move point, say, to the `p` in the second line, and type `M-x comment-line`, the line gets commented out and point ends up on the left parenthesis in the third line. If I type `M-x comment-line-leave-point` instead, the line gets commented out and point is still on `p` afterwards.

Comment: Interesting. It may have to do with my Prelude config?

Comment: See if it works for you when you start Emacs with the `-Q` option which will not load any of your configurations.

Comment: Actually, I may have found when it happens: Only when I am in babel blocks. When I am in a .el file commenting even the original function comment-line works fine, but inside a elisp block, it will go up the first line. Weird, innit?

Comment: Does that happen with `-Q` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly identical behaviour. Only within blocks.

Comment: So, just to clarify: you're talking about `org-mode`? Because your question does not mention that, nor is it among the tags you put with your question. As I wrote above, for an `elisp-buffer`, my answer seems to do what you want at least for me.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question and insert the exact code snippet you're trying out and for which `comment-line` does not show your preferred behavior? That should make it a lot easier to get you what you're after.